# Create NextJS with .Net Core

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, next.js

I need to create a solution that has its frontend in NextJS and its backend in .NET6.
I need them to be created in one solution, so they can be hosted in one website using IIS10.

I see that visual studio 2022 has a template for React. I tried to use it, and removed the React app and installed NextJS instead. But I have an error saying that the proxy cannot be found.
I also had written server.js but it seems that VS is always using Microsoft SPA lib.

Is there a template for working with NextJS and .NET with the proxy configuration ready and setup?!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio not have a specific built-in template for working with Next.js and .NET together out of the box.

It's a interesting question, and I have found something, let me share you.

[1. Next.js meets ASP .NET Core — a story of performance and love at long tail](https://medium.com/@david.nissimoff/next-js-meets-asp-net-core-a-story-of-performance-and-love-at-long-tail-41cf9231b2de)

[2. SPA-Identity-Server-Authenticate-Sample](https://github.com/thanhbao0408/SPA-Identity-Server-Authenticate-Sample)

[3. NextjsStaticHosting-AspNetCore](https://github.com/davidnx/NextjsStaticHosting-AspNetCore)

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a while and I came up with some conclusions:

- SSR can not be used in this case.
- VS has no template for this.
- We can use SSG, check this :https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/nextjs
  but this will use serviceStack.net.
  There is a tool named "x" on the NuGet website, that is used to setup the template.