# Running NextJS Inside ASP.NET Core App Hosted on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, next.js

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC Application with React. I've tried to replace React app with NextJs. Everything is fine in development mode. But I can't figure out how to configure it to deploy on Azure? Is it possible?

Comment: [Hope this answer could be useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76787333/7687666)